# How to pass callback functions with parameters from parent to child components?

Tags: reactjs, function, components, office-fabric

I'm really new to ReactJS framework.
I'm trying to pass a callback function from parent to child component.

What i'm trying to pass is a callback function (changeState) to a child component. The child component is a fabric-ui button and this function will be called when clicking on the button.

**Parent code : only the necessary code**

```
public constructor(props: {}) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      columns: [],
      hasError:false,
      sortedItems: []
    };  
    this.changeState = this.changeState.bind(this);
  }
public changeState = (itemId:React.ReactText)=>{
    const resolvedKey='Status';
    const idKey='Status';
    const item = this.state.sortedItems!.filter(ite => ite[idKey] === itemId)[0];
    item[resolvedKey] = 'Résolu';
  }
<ResolveButton disabled={isResolved} uniqueId={fieldContent} changeState={this.changeState  } />
```

**Child code**

```
import { PrimaryButton } from 'office-ui-fabric-react/lib/Button';
import * as React from 'react';

export interface IHandleChange {
    changeState: (itemId:React.ReactText)=>void;
    disabled:boolean;
    uniqueId:string| number;
}
export class ResolveButton extends React.Component<IHandleChange, {}> {
    constructor(props:any) {

        super(props);
    }
    public handleClick = () => {
        this.props.changeState(this.props.uniqueId);
        alert(`Item ${this.props.uniqueId}`);
    }

    public render(): JSX.Element {
        return (
            <div>
                {
                    !this.props.disabled && 
                    <PrimaryButton
                        data-automation-id="test"
                        text="Résolu"
                        onClick={this.handleClick}
                        allowDisabledFocus={true}
                    />
                }
            </div>
        );
    }
}
export default ResolveButton;
```

The problem is that the child component is not even created when i execute the code above. However the child component is created when i don't pass the callback function (changestate).
This has nothing to do with the parameters disabled and uniqueId passed to the child components. what i'm trying to say is that if i try to remove changeState in the child node interface the child component is well created, however once i introduce changeState in the interface and try to pass it from the parent component the child is never shown in the DOM.

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand the problem itself, your last two sentences. Can you describe it in detailed? So the button is only rendered when the disabled prop is `false`..
Where the `isResolved` variable is coming from in the parent? Isn't it part of the state?

Comment: I modified my question to try to answer your question. Please take a look.

Answer (score 0):

If `isResolved` variable is not part of the state in parent component, its change will not re-render the tree. It might be the problem.